# Kettle Table Input Thread

Tags: multithreading, kettle, pdi

When I run a transformation at Kettle that have a Table Input, if I access the process list of my database, I see more than one process running with the MySQL of my table input step.

So my question is, is it kettle using threads to run the step or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kettle is a [Dataflow programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming). It means that each steps of a transformation runs on its own thread, independently of the others.

Each thread waits for data from the input step(s), process them and deliver them on the output step(s). The data is grouped in packs of about 1000 rows to optimize speed.

This flexibility of processing all the step at the same time has many advantages and explains some otherwise strange behavior, like the fact that the number of steps in the execution history table (at the bottom) are often multiples of 1000, and the the auto-lock issue : When you Input a table that you also truncate in an Output table, then Kettle enter in an auto-lock, each steps waiting for the other to finish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!